# Intel TBB. Распаралелливание вложенных циклов. Интеграл

Tags: c++, многопоточность, распараллеливание

Хочу распараллелить алгоритм нахождения интеграла с помощью tbb. Но похоже я что-то неправильно делаю. Функция IntegralTBB возвращает каждый раз новое значение, похоже гонка данных. Как исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tbb/tbb.h"

double IntegralSeq(const double a1, const double b1,
                const double a2, const double b2,
                const double h)
{
    int n1, n2;
    // локальная переменная
    // для подсчета интеграла
    double sum = 0.0f;

    // координата точки сетки по оси x
    // координата точки сетки по оси y
    double x, y;
    // количество точек сетки интегрирования
    // n1 - по координате x
    // n2 - по координате y
    n1 = (int)(b1 - a1) / h;
    n2 = (int)(b2 - a2) / h;

    for(int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
        {
            //вычисление координат точки
            x = a1 + i * h + h / 2;
            y = a2 + j * h + h / 2;
            //вычисление интеграла
            sum += ((exp(sin(x * M_PI) * cos(y * M_PI)) + 1) /
                    ((b1 - a1) * (b2 - a2))) * h * h;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

double IntegralTBB(const double a1, const double b1,
            const double a2, const double b2,
            const double h)
{
    int n1, n2;

    n1 = (int)(b1 - a1) / h;
    n2 = (int)(b2 - a2) / h;

    return  tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range2d<int>(0,n1,0,n2),0.f,[&](const tbb::blocked_range2d<int> & r, float sum)
    {
        for(int i = r.rows().begin(); i != r.rows().end(); ++i) {
            for(int j = r.cols().begin(); j != r.cols().end() ; ++j)
            {
                double x = a1 + i * h + h / 2;
                double y = a2 + j * h + h / 2;
                sum += (exp(sin(x * M_PI) * cos(y * M_PI)) + 1) /
                        ((b1 - a1)*(b2 - a2) * h * h);

            }
        }
        return sum;
    },std::plus<int>());
}

int main()
{
    tbb::tick_count t0 = tbb::tick_count::now();

    double res = IntegralSeq(0.0f, 6.0f, 0.0, 6.0, 0.001);

    tbb::tick_count t1 = tbb::tick_count::now();

    std:: cout  << " result seq:" << res << " time:" << (t1-t0).seconds();
    t0 = tbb::tick_count::now();
    res = IntegralTBB(0.0f, 6.0f, 0.0, 6.0, 0.001);

    t1 = tbb::tick_count::now();

    std:: cout  << " result tbb:" << res << " time:" << (t1-t0).seconds();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::plus<int>()`, а должно быть `float`... в остальном вроде всё в порядке.... и раз уж все вычисления проходят в double, то сумму я тоже сделал бы в double...

Comment: Ым... Может все таки `n1 = (int) ((b1 - a1) / h);`?

Comment: Также формулы для каждого слагаемого - разные в двух версиях. Скобки расставлены по-разному. В первой версии `h * h` в числителе, а во второй - в знаменателе.